# Out of memory error on screen rotation with large Drawable

Tags: android, image, memory, memory-leaks, webview

I have a bit of difficulties to understand memory issues with Android. The problem is that when I rotate the screen twice, I get an OutOfMemory error when allocating a WebView containing a large image. My image isn't even that big 936*682 24-bit PNG, 50.5 KB.

Here is my activity :

```
public class IndoorMapActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.indoor_map);    
    }

}
```

In my layout, I basically only have a custom ImageWebView.

Here is the custom ImageWebView constructor:

```
public ImageWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    mContext = context;

    this.loadUrl("file:///android_res/drawable/ground.png");
    this.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    this.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.MEDIUM);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is a known bug in Android. You can find the details [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9375). This issue has been fixed in Android 2.2.

Comment: how would I include the BitmapFactory inside a WebView? I load my image using webView.loadUrl(String url)

Comment: Sorry about the bitmap factory answer, that was foolish. Let me know if changing the SDK version solves your problem.

Comment: Yes solved it. According to a comment in your link, you need to add the WebView programmatically instead of adding it in an xml layout. The comment also says the bug HASN'T been fixed after 2.2. I can confirm as I using 2.3.3

Comment: Thanks for the link by the way!

Comment: Well, in one of the comments Romain Guy claimed that it had been fixed in 2.2, so I assumed that it must have been :P